# Computer wakes up from sleep and drains battery (lid malfunction?)

Tags: windows-11, sleep, power-management

My Thinkpad P14s Gen 1 wakes up on the middle of the night, and drains the battery from 100% to 0%. I have tried every recommendation on the internet, but cannot seem to fix it.

The power configuration option in Devices is not available (IDK if it's a bug or a configuration of the thinkpads), but to be sure, last night I left the computer on my desk, with nothing connected (to avoid events of waking it up due to a usb), and still drained the battery.

I ran a sleep study, and there are events from last night every couple of seconds, where it looks like the computer transitions to sleep, and then wakes up again. Here's a screenshot of them. This log repeats every minute, until the battery drains completely. It says something about the lid, but I'm not sure if the lid is waking it up, or sending it to sleep.

Any recommendation on how to solve this problem, or how to get a better insight on what may be causing it, would be highly appreciated.

EDIT1: I performed a test where I put to sleep with the lid open, and it does not lead to significant battery drain. However, with the lid closed, it drained like it was on and running. The laptop is still under warranty. Should I start a claim?

[image: Sleep Study report]

Comment: Modern Standby related, maybe?

Comment: I only have S0 available:
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) Network Connected
    Hibernate

Comment: I have left X1 Lenovo machines sleeping overnight. No issues. Make sure Power Plan is Balanced. Update All with System Updater. Reset the power plan to default and test.

Comment: Leaving an unplugged laptop on sleep overnight will drain the battery *somewhat*, even if the laptop does *not* wake. That constant cycling is bad for the battery, shortening the service life. Better to either *hibernate*, using **no** power overnight, or leave it on charge. It will **not** overcharge.

Comment: I understand that there should be an energy drain, but not 100% of the battery in 7 hours. I have tried different power plans and it's the same.

Comment: Never diagnose what you can RMA. Your time is money.